# Create nodes from string variable

Tags: xslt

I need to create nodes from string , example for that

root1/root2/root3

i want it to generate nodes like that

```
<node name="root1">
     <node name="root2">
         <node name="root3"/>
     </node>
</node>
```

I tried this style sheet

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="root" select="'root1/root2/root3'"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="createNodes">
    <xsl:with-param name="root" select="$root"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createNodes">
    <xsl:param name="root"/>
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rootPath" select="tokenize($root,'/') "/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$rootPath">
        <xsl:element name="node">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="createNodes">
                <xsl:with-param name="caption" select="$rootPath"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem i get this output

```
<node name="root1">
<node name="root2">
<node name="root3">
```

Need your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically rather than looping over each item, you need to break down the string removing the first item as you go, that way you will get a nested result.

This should work:

```
<xsl:template name="createNodes">
  <xsl:param name="root"/>
  <xsl:if test="$root">
    <node name="{substring-before(concat($root,'/'),'/')}">
      <xsl:call-template name="createNodes">
        <xsl:with-param name="root" select="substring-after($root,'/')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </node>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Refactored: Literal Result Elements and Attribute Value Template, normalizated parameter to handle singleton item in sequence, strip variable declaration used only once in the same context scope. **Do note this is XSLT 1.0 solution**