# xalan:nodeset not rendering any node but just text

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I have an input xml file that contains an element which in turns has xml text in it. I want to read the element text and then make it into a node set so I can search thing with xpath. This is the piece:

```
<TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_XML><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TRANSACTION>
<VERSION>1.3</VERSION>
<SCREEN>something123</SCREEN>
</TRANSACTION>
]]></TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_XML>
```

In this case I want to get the value **something123**.

The problem is that if I put (hardcode) the section of the inner xml file in the xsl, **xalan:nodeset()** works fine, but it does not work when I use **xsl:value-of**. oXygen XMLeditor is showing me that the result of value-of has become a plain text, not a node.

The following works:

```
    <xsl:variable name="statementSummaryData">
        <ss_Set>
            <TRANSACTION>
                <VERSION>1.3</VERSION>
                <SCREEN>something123
                </SCREEN>
            </TRANSACTION>
        </ss_Set>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" name="ssTemplatesNodeSet" select="xalan:nodeset($statementSummaryData)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ssTemplatesNodeSet//SCREEN,' ')"/>
```

The following does not work. The **<ss_Set>** element becomes a node, but the output of value-of becomes plain text inside <ss_Set>:

```
    <xsl:variable name="statementSummaryWithHeader">
           <xsl:value-of select="TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_XML" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statementSummaryWithNoHeader">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($statementSummaryWithHeader,'?>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="statementSummaryData">
    <ss_Set>
    <xsl:value-of select="$statementSummaryWithNoHeader" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </ss_Set>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" name="ssTemplatesNodeSet" select="xalan:nodeset($statementSummaryData)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ssTemplatesNodeSet//SCREEN,' ')"/>
```

The following does not work either:

```
    <xsl:variable name="statementSummaryWithHeader">
           <xsl:value-of select="TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_XML" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statementSummaryWithNoHeader">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($statementSummaryWithHeader,'?>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statementSummaryData">
        <ss_Set>
           <xsl:value-of xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" select="xalan:nodeset($statementSummaryWithNoHeader)"/>
        </ss_Set>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" name="ssTemplatesNodeSet" select="xalan:nodeset($statementSummaryData)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ssTemplatesNodeSet//SCREEN,' ')"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges. The `node-set()` function can take a *result-tree-fragment* and convert it into a *node-set*. It cannot turn *CDATA* into parsable markup.

To learn what you can do in order to extract the string you want, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777846/3016153

Comment: I believe there are some implementations of node-set() which, if given a string, will do a parse-xml() on it -- but I don't know if the Xalan implementation is one of those.

Comment: @MichaelKay I believe we had this conversation before. I am not aware of any `node-set()` implementation that will do that. I know for certain that Xalan's will not: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5EF

Comment: Ok, I got it. So I am going to use substring-before and sub-string after to get the output of that particular inner element; however, I just see another way to do it by dynamically building the tree by creating nodes using <node name="mix-of-substring-before-and-sub-string-after-here">. For more info go here (thanks Michael for your help):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418493/create-nodes-from-string-variable

Comment: @guasqueño You can't do that and preserve the hierarchy. You need an XML parser - and it's not feasible to build one using XSLT, certainly not XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can't now find any evidence of implementations of xx:node-set() that work this way. It's a folk memory of bug reports against Saxon (more than one, I'm sure) alleging that it should work that way because it did so in other products. Perhaps those products are no longer with us.